# Is writing stored procedure has any performance gain over sql queries in cosmosdb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am working on a project in which we have lots of queries in a sequence that are written in code and executed by C# SDK. I am wondering is there any performance gain if I move them in a stored procedure.

Example Queries:

1. Fetch the record by id
2. fetch the other record by FK
3. Update the relation and save to database

As you can see here we have 3 queries in a sequence is there any performance gain if this is written in stored procedure? Is it good idea to write stored procedures at all for such queries?

Comment: You can benchmark any performance differences (and RU costs) to see if this helps. Just keep this in mind: A stored procedure is scoped to a single partition of a container. If your additional query, by foreign key, is in a different partition, a stored procedure won't help.

Comment: @David ` If your additional query, by foreign key, is in a different partition, a stored procedure won't help.` It is help full

Answer (score 4):

For your scenario a stored procedure could be beneficial in that it could do the operation as an acid transaction, provided the data all resides on the same logical partition. This is what David noted above.

Stored procedures are not recommended for high concurrent read operations (i.e. queries). The reason is stored procedures only operate on the primary replica. Because throughput is applied equally to all four replicas, you are only going to get 1/4 of the provisioned throughput for these operations.

Stored procedures provide the most benefit when you are doing multiple insert/update operations as you can send an array of items to update in your parameters. This reduces the number of requests and reduces latency for the same amount of work.

I should point out that the scenario you describe with fetching a record and then fetching another record by FK is concerning. You do not want to use Cosmos DB like a relational database. I would encourage you to read the Concept docs on Cosmos and understand modeling and partitioning concepts before getting too far. Additionally, you should also understand  what Change Feed is in Cosmos DB. Change Feed is typically how you would maintain "referential integrity" between different containers in Cosmos DB where you would have a many-to-many relationship between two different containers with different partition keys.